How to display all the scores in every quiz in each module?
I create an e learning module with quiz. However when user is done in taking it display only one of the scores in each module.
Here is the example:
It display when I Take quiz in module 1 :
Fundamentals of Networking: Score - 10
Network Tools and Testing Devices: Score - 0
Network Cables: Score -0
It display when I Take quiz in module 2 :
Fundamentals of Networking: Score - 0
Network Tools and Testing Devices: Score - 10
Network Cables: Score -  0
It display when I Take quiz in module 3 :
Fundamentals of Networking: Score - 0
Network Tools and Testing Devices: Score - 0
Network Cables: Score -  7
It should be like this:
when I Take quiz in module 1 :
Fundamentals of Networking: Score - 10
Network Tools and Testing Devices: Score - 0
Network Cables: Score -0
It display when I Take quiz in module 2 :
Fundamentals of Networking: Score - 10
Network Tools and Testing Devices: Score - 10
Network Cables: Score -  0
It display when I Take quiz in module 3 :
Fundamentals of Networking: Score - 10
Network Tools and Testing Devices: Score - 10
Network Cables: Score -  7
here is my code:
@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def submit_quiz():
global email
global quiz_attempts
users = []
attempts = []
scores = {'Fundamentals of Networking': 0, 'Network Tools and Testing Devices': 0, 'Network Cables': 0}
quiz_files = ["questions1.txt", "questions2.txt", "questions3.txt"]

for idx, quiz_file in enumerate(quiz_files):
    quiz = []
    questions_file = open(quiz_file, "r")
    questions = questions_file.read().splitlines()
    questions_file.close()
    number = 0

    for number, question in enumerate(questions):
        question_object = create_question_object(question, number)
        quiz.append(question_object)

    for idx in range(0, len(quiz)):
        mcq = "mcq" + str(idx + 1)
        attempts.append(request.form.get(mcq))

    print("Length of quiz:", len(quiz))
    print("Length of attempts:", len(attempts))

    if quiz_file == "questions1.txt":
        quiz_name = "Fundamentals of Networking"
    elif quiz_file == "questions2.txt":
        quiz_name = "Network Tools and Testing Devices"
    else:
        quiz_name = "Network Cables"

    for idx in range(0, len(quiz)):
        if quiz[idx].correct == attempts[idx]:
            scores[quiz_name] += 1

users_data_file = open("users_data.txt", "r")
users = users_data_file.read().splitlines()
users_data_file.close()

for idx in range(0, len(users)):
    if email == get_field(users[idx], 1):
        users[idx] = (
            str(get_field(users[idx], 0))
            + ","
            + str(get_field(users[idx], 1))
            + ","
            + str(get_field(users[idx], 2))
            + ","
            + str(scores["Fundamentals of Networking"])
            + ","
            + str(scores["Network Tools and Testing Devices"])
            + ","
            + str(scores["Network Cables"])
        )

user_data_file = open("users_data.txt", "w")
for user in users:
    print(user, file=user_data_file, sep="\n")
user_data_file.close()

return render_template("user.html")

@app.route("/show", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def results():
global email
users = []
users_data_file = open("users_data.txt", "r")
users = users_data_file.read().splitlines()
users_data_file.close()

# Initialize dictionaries to store scores for each quiz
scores = {
    'Fundamentals of Networking': 0,
    'Network Tools and Testing Devices': 0,
    'Network Cables': 0
}

for user in users:
    # Check if the user's email matches
    if email == get_field(user, 1):
        # Update scores for each quiz from the user's data
        scores['Fundamentals of Networking'] = get_field(user, 3)
        scores['Network Tools and Testing Devices'] = get_field(user, 4)
        scores['Network Cables'] = get_field(user, 5)

return render_template("result.html", scores=scores)


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

when a user accesses endpoint submit you seem to initialize their scores to
 {'Fundamentals of Networking': 0, 'Network Tools and Testing Devices': 0, 'Network Cables': 0}

though no previously stored scores get read and written in the dictionary, overriding their old scores to 0.
on a side note: may i recommend using
with open("users_data.txt", "w") as user_data_file :
    for user in users:
        user_data_file.write(user)

instead of manually opening and closing files?
